# Is there a browser event that fires when the OS X scroll bar style changes?

Tags: javascript, macos, webkit, dom-events, osx-lion

OS X Lion and above allow the user to turn on/off iOS-style floating scroll bars - either manually via System Preferences, or by plugging in a mouse.

WebKit-based browsers (and maybe Opera?) switch their scroll bar style immediately - **is there an event that fires when this occurs?** (WebKit-only is just fine)

---

### Some notes:

- OS X fires `NSPreferredScrollerStyleDidChangeNotification` when the user switches their scroll bar style
- WebKit does not appear to subscribe to this event (no hits when grepping for it).
- I suspect that WebKit is handling this via the `NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification` event (which, I assume, fires for the scroll view's content view).
- WebKit handles this event [within `-[WebHTMLView _frameOrBoundsChanged]`](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebKit/mac/WebView/WebHTMLView.mm#L1199), which seems like one potential re-layouting point.
- There are also references to this notification in `WebPDFView` and the inspector's `WebNodeHighlight` - both seem unrelated to this case.
- [`-[WebDynamicScrollBarsView adjustForScrollOriginChange]`](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebKit/mac/WebView/WebDynamicScrollBarsView.mm#L244) seems to indicate that events may not be fired (if so, it'd be nice to see some confirmation)

---

Polling for changes is not an acceptable answer to me (performance & the layout jumping after the user changes the value).

Comment: Asked myself that, too a while ago, but stopped looking as IE (Windows) and FF (all systems) don't support that. So far I know it is completely client based controlled by MAC OS X, but maybe someone knows better.

Comment: Yeah, in my particular cases, I'm looking to change style & behavior when it changes (specifically on OS X WebKit-based browsers).  It's a pretty minor stylistic thing; the user can refresh the page to recalculate things, but it'd be nice to be responsive to that change (and I definitely want to avoid polling scroll bar widths or something)

Comment: @Nevir: This sounds like a good suggestion to [send Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Good call!  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From everything I've read thus far, **there is no DOM event fired** during this style transition.

The most conclusive example is to create an `overflow: auto` div, and then log all of its events (in Safari or Chrome) via [`monitorEvents`](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/chrome-developer-tools-monitorevents).  Nothing is logged when changing the scroll bar style.

I have an [open webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85287) on the issue (though it's probably minor enough that we won't see any movement on it).